# How to track JSNI Errors in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, jsni

When I use GWT JSNI there can be errors in my JSNI JavaScript code like this:

```
try {
...
} catch(error) {
 console.log(error);
}
```

**How can I track this error in the GWT logging system or with the GWT uncaughtException?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exceptions thrown in JSNI methods are exposed to the Java code as [`JavaScriptException`s](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptException.html), and you can easily wrap the object caught in JS in a `JavaScriptException` if you need to give it to GWT APIs that need an exception (such as `GWT.log`).

```
try {
  …
} catch (e) {
  var ex = @com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException::new(Ljava/lang/Object;)(e);
  @com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT::log(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)("Error doing …", ex);
}
```

In GWT 2.6.1+ you can use [`JsonLogRecordClientUtil`](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.6.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/logging/client/JsonLogRecordClientUtil.java).`throwableAsJson(e)` to turn any exception into a String to, e.g. send it to your server or display it.

In GWT 2.6.0+ you can use [`GWT.reportUncaughtException`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#reportUncaughtException%28java.lang.Throwable%29) to report any exception to the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` if any, or to the browser otherwise:

```
try {
  …
} catch (e) {
  var ex = @com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException::new(Ljava/lang/Object;)(e);
  @com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT::reportUncaughtException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)(ex);
}
```

That said, in most case you don't need this: just let the exception propagate outside your JSNI method and catch the `JavaScriptException` in Java-land.

Comment: Could you please post an example how to use throwableAsJson with JSNI?

Comment: Not _“with JSNI”_, just _with a JavaScriptException_. Or you need to better explain your problem. I added some sample code calling GWT.log from JSNI, but you shouldn't need this.

Comment: Why didn't I need this?

Comment: Could you post an example for the  JsonLogRecordClientUtil please?

Comment: Same as the other two, but it returns some JSON as a string instead of logging/reporting the exception; so you have to somehow log that JSON. On the "why wouldn't you need this" side, read the last paragraph of my answer: you shouldn't need to catch exceptions in JS, let them propagate outside the JSNI and catch them in Java; if they're in "callbacks", then they'll be reported to your `GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler` as `JavaScriptException`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an JSNI method `log()` and call

`$wnd.log(JSON.stringify(error));` and log to the GWT logger.